# iOS WidgetKit: remote images fails to load

Tags: swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I'm observing a bizarre thing: in the new widgets far too often **remote images are not being displayed** even though the image has been successfully loaded and placed in cache.

For image downloading I've tried:

- SDWebImageSwiftUI
- Kingfisher
- SwURL

All of them indicate that image loading succeed, but the actual widget is not showing it.

```
struct TestWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        WebImage(url: URL(string: "https://miro.medium.com/max/3840/0*TLqp5Uwavd-U_xrs.jpg"))
                        .onSuccess()
                        .resizable()
    }
}
```

On the second run of the debugger - with image loading from cache - I get the image displayed, but never(?) on initial run.

It feels like that in onSuccess I need to trigger UI-invalidation? But how?

(Since it happens to literally every image-lib I try - I don't think that it's something off in the libs)

**Environment:**

- iOS 14 Beta 3 (both device and simulators)
- Xcode 12 Beta 3
- During the debug run, memory use is around 15mb

Comment: I can display the image on the widget by RemoteImage, but sometime it will not display due to widget policy. Might be the same problem here

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned by Konstantin, it is not supported to load images **asynchronously**. There are 2 options to load network image in widgets

1. Either fetch all the images in **TimelineProvider** and inject them to the views directly.

   OR
2. Use `Data(contentsOf: url)` to fetch the image. This way it still fetches them synchronously but the code is cleaner.  Sample code -

   ```
   struct NetworkImage: View {

     private let url: URL?

     var body: some View {

       Group {
        if let url = url, let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url), 
          let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

          Image(uiImage: uiImage)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
         } 
         else {
          Image("placeholder-image")
         }
       }
     }

   }
   ```

This view can simply be use like this -

```
NetworkImage(url: url)
```

Comment: Did you intend the url property to be private? Otherwise, it cannot be set elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

Got it: it's simply not supported and you aim to load images inside TimelineProvider:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652581

Comment: This helps me a lot, I've been struggling for this for whole night, thanks!

Comment: Does it mean I cannot use SwiftUI component (eg: https://github.com/dmytro-anokhin/url-image) to render image? Should I predownload the image binary into local in TImelineProvider first?