# How to load WKWebView in Widget preview SwiftUI iOS 14

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

How to load wkwebview in widget swiftui ios 14 I am doing something like this (code attached) but it is showing me this image https://www.sendspace.com/file/nw002i (download image from this link) looking forward to your answers by the way i am new on swiftui as well as I am curious is apple allow this thing or not?

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import Photos

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date())
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate)
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}

struct WebWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
     var body: some View {
        WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
    }      
}

@main
struct WebWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "WebWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WebWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}

struct WebWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {    
    static var previews: some View {
        WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
    }

}
    
struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicator>) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }
}

struct LoadingView<Content>: View where Content: View {

    @Binding var isShowing: Bool
    var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {

                self.content()
                    .disabled(self.isShowing)
                    .blur(radius: self.isShowing ? 3 : 0)

                VStack {
                    Text("Loading...")
                    ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .large)
                }
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2,
                       height: geometry.size.height / 5)
                .background(Color.secondary.colorInvert())
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .opacity(self.isShowing ? 1 : 0)

            }
        }
    }

}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!))
    }
}
struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    let request: URLRequest
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        return WKWebView()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are some limitations to which Views you can use in Widgets.

As Widget Views don't allow interaction (with the exception of `Link`) you're not allowed to use ScrollView in Widgets. And I suspect WKWebView is built on top of UIScrollView.

If you want to display some URL contents you have two options:

- fetch data in the TimelineProvider and pass to an Entry
- use `Data(contentsOf: url)` as proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63387751/8697793).